# change hover color button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want the `div` `onhover` background color to change to blue once button is clicked.

In this example, it changes the normal background color as well:

```js
$(document).on("click", "button", function() {
  $(".box").on("mouseover", function() {
    $(".box").css("background", "blue")
  });
})
```

```css
.box:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Change hover color</button>
<hr/>
<div class="box">Hello</div>
```

Comment: bad idea to bind events inside of events. Every click, you bind another event....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```js
$(document).on("click","button",function(){

    $(".box").on("mouseover",function(){$(".box").css("background","blue")});
    $(".box").on("mouseout",function(){$(".box").css("background","")});

})
```

```css
.box:hover{background:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Change hover color</button>
<hr/>

<div class="box">Hello</div>
```

Comment: I liked yours. I cant make use of classes because the code I'm working on is too advanced....your works +1!

Answer (score 1):

make use of [hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) jquery function and make use of class instead of css

```
$(".box").hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass("hover_me");
}, function(){
    $(this).removeClass("hover_me");
});
```

css class

```
.hover_me {
  background: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Jquery DOM was incorrect,

Here is how it does

$(document).ready(function(){

// jQuery methods go here...

});

```js
$(function(){
$('button').click(function(){
 $(".box").on("mouseover",function(){
 $('.box').css("background","blue")
 });
   $(".box").on("mouseout",function(){$(".box").css("background","")
   });

})
});
```

```css
.box:hover{background:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Change hover color</button>
<hr/>

<div class="box">Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your jQuery, add an eventhandler for mouseout, to remove the background.

```
$(document).on("click", "button", function () {
    $(".box").on("mouseover", function () {
        $(".box").css("background", "blue")
    });
    $(".box").on("mouseout", function () {
        $(".box").css("background", "none")
    });
})
```